# get total number of comments for entity using query over

Tags: nhibernate, join, queryover

I am trying to get the total comments for an entity yet I am getting back incorrect results.

How would I get a Task and its comments counts (eagerly loaded)

```
        var tasks = _session.QueryOver<Task>(() => taskAlias)
                                 .Where(x => x.OrganizationID == null)
                                 .Fetch(x => x.AssignedUser).Eager
                                 .Fetch(x => x.Owner).Eager
                                 .Fetch(x => x.Comments).Eager
                                 .List();
```

#### This returns:

Task.ID 1 Comments 3
Task.ID 1 Comments 3
Task.ID 1 Comments 3

Task.ID 2 Comments 2
Task.ID 2 Comments 2

Task.ID 3 Comments 1

I want:

Task.ID 1 Comments 3

Task.ID 2 Comments 2

Task.ID 3 Comments 1

My fluent mappings are:

`HasMany(x => x.Comments).Table("tComments").ForeignKeyConstraintName("fT_Task_ID").KeyColumn("fC_Resource_ID").Where("fC_Type = 'Task'").ReadOnly();`

Comment: So your saying your root entity is repeating?  if so use:  .TransformUsing(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())

Comment: I just want to know why the root is repeating - looking at my mappings that should not happen right?

Comment: It's happening because your query isn't identifying that the root should be unique.  In the back end your doing a join on multiple tables which will result in a cross product coming back (SQL). The DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer tells Nhibernate that the root element needs to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, the problem is that your getting the correct data back, it's just duplicating at the root level. If this is the case, change your query to:

```
var tasks = _session.QueryOver<Task>(() => taskAlias)
                                 .Where(x => x.OrganizationID == null)
                                 .Fetch(x => x.AssignedUser).Eager
                                 .Fetch(x => x.Owner).Eager
                                 .Fetch(x => x.Comments).Eager
                                 .TransformUsing(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
                                 .List();
```

When you have an entity and it contains a collection of entities and you tell NHibernate to fetch the collections eagerly the SQL that is generated will essentially return as:

```
TASK 1 - COMMENTS 1A
TASK 1 - COMMENTS 1B
TASK 1 - COMMENTS 1C
TASK 2 - COMMENTS 2A
TASK 2 - COMMENTS 2B
...
```

The DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer is what we use to tell NHibernate that the root element should be unique. As your original code didn't have the transformer your root elements are duplicated.

Comment: thanks your answer fixed my issue, I was just concerned that should not happen for a 1 to m mapping.

Comment: The problem with this solution is: Skip & Take do not work as expected, so I have unchecked this answer as it does not resolve my problem. Have you tried skip and take with your answer?

Comment: Check out this article.  http://kuhnel.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/paging-eager-fetched-nhibernate-collections-efficiently/

Comment: Or this page gets to the root of the issue without all the explanation:  http://programminghacks.net/2012/07/15/nhibernate-paging-by-root-entity-with-eager-join-fetch-of-a-child-collection/